# Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngbTypeahead' since it isn't a known property of 'input

Tags: angular

Does not work **ngbTypeahead**. The console returns the following message:

```
    Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngbTypeahead' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("                   <input id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ERROR ->][ngbTypeahead]="search"/>
          <hr>

"): ng:///ProductModule/UserProductsComponent.html@86:100
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at TemplateParser.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:24668)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:34621)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:34596)
    at compiler.js:34497
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:34497)
    at compiler.js:34367
    at Object.then (compiler.js:474)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34366)
```

file **user-products.component.html** in which it is placed:

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
     <input id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search"/>
</div>
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule,  ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule,  Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';   
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { ProductModule } from './product/product.module'; 
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
// ... 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(), 
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,  
    ProductModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes )
    // ... 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

class **user-products.component.ts** in which the method is search:

```
import { User, UserType } from '../../model';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth.service';
import { Product, ProductType } from './module-product';  
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/'; 
import { NgbTypeahead } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
// ...
const states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virgin Islands'];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-products',
  templateUrl: './user-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-products.component.css']
})

export class UserProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  product: Product;
  user: User;
  UserType = UserType;
  product_name: string;
  product_type: ProductType;
  ProductType = ProductType;
  product_desc: string;
  produktForm: FormGroup;
  products: Product; 
  products_: any;
  users$: Observable<User[]>; 

  public model: any;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router ) {  }

 search = (text$: Observable<string>) => text$
  .debounceTime(200)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
   : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))

  ngOnInit() {
    this.produktForm = this.fb.group({
      product_name: this.product_name, 
      product_type: this.product_type, 
      product_desc: this.product_desc 
    });
  }
  // ...
}
```

version:  @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.1.0

I do not know how to correct the error.

[image]

file **.angular-cli.json** :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "test-panel"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

@Niladri I updated the code, but the error still occurs.

The file `.angular-cli.json` only contains a different configuration for libraries (but the bootstrap files are there for me), but everything else is the same as in @Niladri.

Comment: I've used this package quite  a bit. Is the component you are trying to use the typeahead in located in a lazy loaded module?

Comment: I don't know if I understood the question well.in the file `app/product/user-products/user-products.component.html` is input, and the component is`app/product/user-products/user-products.component.ts` Do you mean calling  TypeaheadModule.forRoot()?

Comment: @user2129896 check my answer .. you are using a wrong import in app.module .. there is a mismatch between ngx-bootstrap and ng-bootstrap

Comment: I updated to the version `ngx-bootstrap@2.0.3`

Comment: @user2129896 but in your question you mentioned `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.1.0` as your version

Comment: ngx-bootstrap does not have that `ngbTypeahead` directive... it has a different name there . So you need to be clear which one you need to use.

Comment: I need to use `[ngbTypeahead]="search"`

Answer (score 3):

I had several modules. Should be set in the main method `NgbModule.forRoot()`, - `app.module.ts`, and in the child `NgbModule`.

test.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
// ...
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

// ... 

@NgModule({
  imports: [

    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule, 
    NgbModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],

  declarations: [
   // ..
  ],

  providers: [ProductsService],

  exports: [ // ..
    ]
})
export class ProductModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a wrong import in your app.module . You are currently importing from `ngx-bootstrap/typeahead` which is a different library for bootstrap 3.

But according to the documentation you should be using `ng-bootstrap` package not from `ngx-bootstrap` to use the directive `[ngbTypeahead]` . So you need to import the below `NgbModule` module like below code in app.module

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    imports : [
        //...
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    //...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now you can using typeahead directive in your component like below

```
<input  id="typeahead-focus"  type="text"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user"  [ngbTypeahead]="search" (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)" (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)" />
```

Working demo

https://stackblitz.com/angular/rdkongmjovr?file=app%2Ftypeahead-basic.html

Official documentation

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples

Edit : Here is the complete code which is working for me . For simplicity I have commented out few service calls using AuthService .

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "./app/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
```

**typeaheaddemo.component.ts**

```
import {NgbTypeahead} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Component,ViewChild,OnInit,Input, } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {FormGroup,FormControl,FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms'
import {ActivatedRoute,Route,Router} from  '@angular/router'
import {ProductType ,Product,User} from '../producttype'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';

const states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa',  'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware',     
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',  'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',    
  'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',  'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-products',
  templateUrl: './typeaheaddemo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./typeaheaddemo.component.css']
})

export class TypeaheaddemoComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  product: Product;
  user: User;
  //UserType = UserType;
  product_name: string;
  product_type: ProductType;
  //ProductType = ProductType;
  product_desc: string;

  produktForm: FormGroup;
  products: Product[];
  userObj: any;
  expid: string;
  id: any;
  products_: any;
  users$: Observable<User[]>;

  model: any;
  @ViewChild('instance') instance: NgbTypeahead;
   focus$ = new Subject<string>();
  click$ = new Subject<string>();

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$
      .debounceTime(200).distinctUntilChanged()
      .merge(this.focus$)
      .merge(this.click$.filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()))
      .map(term => (term === '' ? states : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10));

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    //this.userObj = this.authService.currentUser;
    //onst userid = this.userObj.userid;

    this.produktForm = this.fb.group({
      product_name: this.product_name, 
      product_type: this.product_type,
      product_desc: this.product_desc 
    });
  }

}
```

**typeaheaddemo.component.html**

```
<label for="typeahead-basic">Search for a state:</label>
<input  id="typeahead-focus"  type="text"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user"  [ngbTypeahead]="search" (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)" (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)" #instance="ngbTypeahead" />
<hr>
<pre>Model: {{ model | json }}</pre>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { TypeaheaddemoComponent } from './typeaheaddemo/typeaheaddemo.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TypeaheaddemoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Make sure that you have imported `FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule` in your app.module otherwise `ngModel and Formbuilder` would not work**

Comment: I've added `imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), TypeaheadModule.forRoot(), ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule, // ..]` did not help

Comment: also: `imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(),  ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule // ...]` but did not help

Comment: `[ngbTypeahead]="search"` highlights the error:
`[Angular] Can't bind to 'ngbTypeahead' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.`

Comment: @user2129896 did you check the stackblitz link above .. it 's working there

Comment: @user2129896 can you post the full html here ? How are you using `@ViewChild('instance') instance: NgbTypeahead;` here?

Comment: please uninstall ngx-bootstrap by using `npm uninstall ngx-bootstrap` . remove ngx-bootstrap from package.json . Delete your node_modules folder and do a fresh npm install again.

Comment: my user-products.component.html : `          <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user" [ngbTypeahead]="search" (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)" (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)" #instance="ngbTypeahead"/>`

Comment: @ Niladri  I have uninstalled `npm install ngx-bootstrap` in the package.json file, there is no `ngx-bootstrap`. After removal, I have to reinstall it?

Comment: No you should only have ng-bootstrap now

Comment: @user2129896 I have updated my answer with complete code which is working for me

Comment: I have : `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.0",` in file `user-products.component.html` for attribute '[ngbTypeahead]="search"' , it still highlights in red and displays an error `Can't bind to 'ngbTypeahead' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.` and for attribute  `#instance="ngbTypeahead"` returns a message: `There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbTypeahead"`

Comment: Ok, I will try to do just like you

Comment: I updated the code, but the error still occurs. I do not have this class `NgbdTypeaheadBasic` I have my `UserProductsComponent` in which I put the `search` method. I have references to bootstrap libraries in the `.angular-cli.json` file

Comment: @user2129896 did you try with my code which I posted above? ignore the stackblitz one

Comment: I added in HTML ` <input  id="typeahead-focus"  type="text"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user"  [ngbTypeahead]="search" (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)" (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)" #instance="ngbTypeahead" />`

Comment: and I added in class: `@ViewChild('instance') instance: NgbTypeahead;
  focus$ = new Subject<string>();
 click$ = new Subject<string>();
 search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
   text$
     .debounceTime(200).distinctUntilChanged()
     .merge(this.focus$)
     .merge(this.click$.filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()))
     .map(term => (term === '' ? states : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))`

Comment: but he is still in error: `There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbTypeahead" ("ead]="search" (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)" (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)" [ERROR ->]#instance="ngbTypeahead" />` I do not have any ideas how to fix it

Comment: Are you able to build and run the application? Did you try to run "npm start"?

Comment: performs the command `ng build` as commented by the code from `[ngbTypeahead] = 'search'`, the application works

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code. I have a bug in the console and underlines in red the line `[ngbTypeahead] ="search"` with error: `Can not bind to 'ngbTypeahead' since it is not a known property of 'input'.`

Comment: But your application is running right with `ng build`?

Comment: yes, the application works correctly but if it comments HTML code with `<input id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search"/>`

Comment: I had the same issue -only in my unit test- and although in component I don't need to import the `NgbModule` because it is already imported in a parent component, test requires it. I solved it like this:
1) `import { NgbModule, NgbTypeaheadConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';` in the top of the test / 
2) `const stub = {NgbTypeAheadConfig: new NgbTypeaheadConfig()};
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [NgbModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: NgbTypeaheadConfig, useValue: stub.NgbTypeAheadConfig }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();` in the test beforeEach